# Python Bar Chart not Displaying Correctly (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-visualization

I have some data I'd like to display in 2 stacked bar charts (side by side).  Using matplotlib.

```
keys=['BF', 'VL', 'GM', 'VM']
data=[[0.10992407597195027, 0.084754817342900857],
 [0.20119173770112833, 0.24308696457787043],
 [0.49912704691619575, 0.53468456580435009],
 [0.18975713941072578, 0.13747365227487865]]
x = range(2)

f, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,5))

plt.bar(x,data[0], label=keys[0])
plt.bar(x,data[1], bottom=data[0], label=keys[1])
plt.bar(x,data[2], bottom=data[1], label=keys[2])
plt.bar(x,data[3], bottom=data[2],label=keys[3])

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

The above code displays the following graph:
[image]

It seems to me that the red bar (VM) has not been stacked on top of the rest of the bars, leading to the strange look of the graph (despite me specifying the correct `bottom` attribute.  The data in each bar should sum to 1 exactly.  How can I fix this?

### EDIT:

I was able to fix the issue by setting the `bottom` attribute to the sum of the lower bars, rather than just the lower one explicitly, using the following rather messy code:

```
plt.bar(x,data[0], width = bar_width, label=keys[0])
plt.bar(x,data[1], width = bar_width, bottom=data[0], label=keys[1])
plt.bar(x,data[2], width = bar_width, bottom=[data[0][i]+data[1][i] for i in x], label=keys[2])
plt.bar(x,data[3], width = bar_width, bottom=[data[0][i]+data[1][i]+data[2][i] for i in x],label=keys[3]
```

Is there a better way to do this?  It doesn't scale well with more bars.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense to iterate through your data and call bar() each time. 
 I haven't tested this but it should be enough to get started.

```
y_pos_1 = y_pos_2 = 0
for k, v in enumerate(data):
  abs_bottom = [y_pos_1, y_pos_2]
  plt.bar(x, v, bottom=abs_bottom, label=keys[k])
  y_pos_1 += v[0]
  y_pos_2 += v[1]
```

Basically just keep a rolling count of the bottom of each bar. Use enumerate() to get the index so we can use that to get the label.